# Is the phrase "refreshing lives" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Someone shared a mail, where among the contents, he said - *its been 14 years of refreshing lives*. We are arguing whether the word refreshing is being used in the right context.

Comment: Further question - When used as a campaign slogan, i.e.  - 14 years of Refreshing Lives. Is that correct?

Comment: *in the right context.* There is no context... Without any context, the example is probably wrong. Please provide context.

Comment: 'They have a fine track record ... it's been 14 years of helping the needy/refreshing lives', //'We've come across many inspirational people in our time in ministry on the island – it's been 14 years of wonderful relationships / refreshing lives' .... Grammatically fine, though perhaps not very idiomatic.

Comment: @ Greybeard, the context is that they wish to run an anniversary campaign. One of the slogan ideas is - 14 years of refreshing lives. 

The debate now is whether it is accurate or not? Grateful for your thoughts.

Comment: @Uch - What definition of “refreshing” are you applying?